# Having trouble linking custom MyWebView with main.xml

Tags: android-webview

I have attempted to extend the WebView class in my application so that I can detect swipes:

```
public class BookOne extends Activity {
public static final String LOG_TAG = "BookOne";
private MyWebView browser;
private WebView listing_area;
private GestureDetector detector;


 public class MyWebView extends WebView {
    GestureDetector gd;
    public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
        super(context, attributes);
        this.
        gd = new GestureDetector(new SwipeDetector());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onTouchEvent 2");
        return (gd.onTouchEvent(event) || super.onTouchEvent(event)); 
    }
};
```

In my main.xml file I've referenced MyWebView as follows:

```
    <mikes.BookOne.BookOne.MyWebView
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:id="@+id/webkit"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

where I believe that mikes.BookOne.BookOne.MyWebView is the fully qualified path to the new class type.

Unfortunately, I'm getting errors in the LogCat window when I try to run it:

`07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{mikes.BookOne/mikes.BookOne.BookOne}:android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class mikes.BookOne.BookOne.MyWebView
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630): Caused by:    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class   mikes.BookOne.BookOne.MyWebView
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:223)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1786)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at mikes.BookOne.BookOne.onCreate(BookOne.java:192)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     ... 11 more
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mikes.BookOne.BookOne.MyWebView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/mikes.BookOne-1.apk]
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:500)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:542)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:671)
07-18 23:14:33.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22630):     ... 22 more`

and the application aborts on load.
The Layout Inflater errors appear to point to the first line of the XML entry in main.xml, but I don't understand where I've gone wrong.  Can anyone help?
Thanks,
MikeS

Comment: The exception error is occurring when I call setContentView at the top of my onCreate() function for the application.  It appears to not find the class type I've defined in my XML file - I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually worked around this problem by defining a LinearLayout view where I wanted the webview in my XML, and then manually generating the webview in my onCreate code:

```
    ViewGroup wkll = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.webkitLinearLayout);      
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams tlp =
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT );
    browser = new MyWebView(this);
    wkll.addView(browser);
    browser.setLayoutParams(tlp);
    browser.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(24);
    browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    browser.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);       
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/cover.html");
```

browser was defined as

```
public MyWebView browser;
```

near the top of my activity.  And the corresponding main.xml includes:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:id="@+id/webkitLinearLayout"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

This does exactly what I want, with the downside that I can't see the layout properly in the XML graphical layout.